# jquery - code wont work when it has been implemented once

Tags: jquery

the biggest problem I have is understanding why some of my code wont work one it has been used once.

i.e.

```
$('input[name=add_y_option]').bind( 'click', function(){
    var ob = $(this);
    var ob_parent = '<tr>' + ob.parents('tr:eq(0)').html() + '</tr>';
    var tbody = ob.parents('tbody:eq(0)');
    var copy = tbody.children(':first').html();
    ob.parents('tr:eq(0)').remove();
    tbody.append('<tr>' + copy + '</tr>');
    tbody.append(ob_parent);
    var inserted = tbody.children(':last');
    return false;
});
```

once I have clicked the button it creates the row, fine. But once i click it again it no longer reconises the button.

Could anyone point me in the right direction.

regards phil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `.bind` to `.live` and it should work fine

`.bind` only applies to objects that exist at load. `.live` applies for current AND future objects

Comment: haha no problem! I TOTALLY understand your frustration - I searched high and low for this and spent days looking for an answer :)